# Javascript, I am not being able to cursor to input box

Tags: javascript

I can't set focus on html input, I tried this code, And it doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById('ember19').focus();
document.getElementById('ember19').click();
document.getElementById('ember19').select();
document.getElementById('ember19').value='Badman55555@hotmail.com';
document.getElementById('ember19').setAttribute('value','Badman55555@hotmail.com');

document.getElementById('ember22').focus();
document.getElementById('ember22').click();
document.getElementById('ember22').select();
document.getElementById('ember22').value='Bad123456';
document.getElementById('ember22').setAttribute('value','Bad123456');
```

Please before answer try your code on this page

```
https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/signin/
```

Comment: Dunno mate, works for me. Maybe you mixed the element ids, email input is `ember18` not `ember19` on that page

Comment: Dude I literally went to the page, did `document.getElementById('ember18').value='abcd'` and it worked on the email field. What's more, I did it again just now. Anyway, have fun I hope you get your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using autofocus

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" autofocus />
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_autofocus.asp

Comment: It doesn't work, I think you did not try it on this page [https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/signin/#/signin?entry=%2Fsignin]

Comment: Can try adding "autofocus" in HTML code, try to load the page

Comment: I added this one **document.querySelector('input').autofocus = true;** , Same problem